# Nginx-Ingress for TCP entrypoint not working

Tags: logstash, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am using Nginx as Kubernetes Ingress controller. After following [this](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/complete-example) simple example I was able to setup this example

Now I am trying to setup TCP entrypoint for logstash with following config

**Logstash** :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: logstash-secret
  namespace: kube-logging
type: Opaque
data:
  tls.crt: "<base64 encoded>" #For logstash.test.domain.com
  tls.key: "<base64 encoded>" #For logstash.test.domain.com

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logstash-config
  namespace: kube-logging
  labels:
    app: logstash
data:
  syslog.conf: |-
    input {
      tcp {
          port => 5050
          type => syslog
      }
    }

    filter {
        grok {
          match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGLINE}"}
        }
    }

    output {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"] #elasticsearch running in same namespace (kube-logging)
        index => "syslog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      }
      stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }

---

kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: logstash
  namespace: kube-logging
  labels:
    app: logstash
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: logstash
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: logstash
    spec:
      #serviceAccountName: logstash
      containers:
      - name: logstash
        image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.2.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
          value: elasticsearch
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
          value: "9200"
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME
          value: elastic
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
          value: changeme
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID
          value:
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH
          value:
        ports:
        - name: logstash
          containerPort: 5050
          protocol: TCP
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/syslog.conf
          readOnly: true
          subPath: syslog.conf
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: logstash-config

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: logstash
  namespace: kube-logging
  labels:
    app: logstash
spec:
  ports:
    - name: tcp-port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5050
      targetPort: 5050
  selector:
    app: logstash
```

**Nginx-Ingress**:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: kube-ingress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-ingress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress
      containers:
      - image: nginx/nginx-ingress:1.5.7
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: nginx-ingress
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
        - name: tcp5050
          containerPort: 5050
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          runAsUser: 101 #nginx
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - ALL
            add:
            - NET_BIND_SERVICE
        env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        args:
          - -nginx-configmaps=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-config
          - -default-server-tls-secret=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-server-secret
          - -v=3 # Enables extensive logging. Useful for troubleshooting.
         #- -report-ingress-status
         #- -external-service=nginx-ingress
         #- -enable-leader-election
         #- -enable-prometheus-metrics
         #- -enable-custom-resources
```

**LoadBalancer** :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-external
  namespace: kube-ingress
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "tcp"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
  - name: tcp5050
    protocol: TCP
    port: 5050
    targetPort: 5050
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
```

**Ingress** :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: logstash-ingress
  namespace: kube-logging
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - logstash.test.domain.com
    secretName: logstash-secret #This has self-signed cert for logstash.test.domain.com
  rules:
  - host: logstash.test.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: logstash
          servicePort: 5050
```

With this config it shows following ,

```
NAME               HOSTS                         ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
logstash-ingress   logstash.test.domain.com                 80, 443   79m
```

Why port 5050 not listed here ?

Just want to expose `logstash` service through public endpoint. When I use 
`openssl s_client -connect logstash.kube-logging.svc.cluster.local:5050` within the cluster I get

```
$ openssl s_client -connect logstash.kube-logging.svc.cluster.local:5050
CONNECTED(00000005)
```

But from outside of the cluster `openssl s_client -connect logstash.test.domain.com:5050` I get

```
$ openssl s_client -connect logstash.test.domain.com:5050
connect: Connection refused
connect:errno=61
```

and

```
$ openssl s_client -cert logstash_test_domain_com.crt -key logstash_test_domain_com.key -servername logstash.test.domain.com:5050
connect: Connection refused
connect:errno=61
```

What I need to do to get this working ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are kind of confused. So let's start by ordering your services and ingress.

First, there are 3 types of services in kubernetes. `ClusterIP` which allows you to expose your deployments internally in k8s. `Nodeport` which is the same as `ClusterIP` but also exposes your deployment through every **node external IP** and a **PORT** which is in the range ~30K-32K. Finally there is the `LoadBalancer` service which is the same as `ClusterIP` but also exposes your app in a specific external IP address assigned by the cloud provider LoadBalancer.

The `NodePort` service you created will make logstash accessible through every node external IP in a random port in the range 30K to 32K; find the port running `kubectl get services | grep nginx-ingress` and check the last column. To get your node's external ip addresses run `kubectl get node -o wide`. The `LoadBalancer` service you created will make logstash accessible through an external IP address in the port 5050. To find out the IP run `kubectl get services | grep nginx-ingress-external`. Finally, you have also created an ingress resource to reach logstash. For this you have defined a host which given TLS will be accessible in port 443 and inbound traffic there will be redirected to logstash's service type `ClusterIP` in port 5050. So there you go you have 3 ways to reach logstash. I would go for the `LoadBalancer` given that it is a specific port.

Comment: I understood `NodePort` Service I created is not helpful here. `logstash` is exposed to public through `LoadBalancer` Service. If all other config is correct why I am not able to access the `logstash` service using public endpoint ?

Comment: Did you check your inbound rules. Maybe cloud provider's firewall is blocking you. Can I have a sample of your LoadBalancer type service and your deployment? That would be great.

Comment: Also, what is the logstash configuration file you are using?

Comment: I just noticed that your deployment has as image `nginx/nginx-ingress:edge` which is an nginx not a logstash. Where is the deployment for logstash?

Comment: Updated with more details.